# datatables reload on ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

hi i made this function where i can delete a row after confirming.
the problem is, after it is deleted, the tables dont reload. i have to refresh the page so that the table can reload. i am new to ajax, and i want to learn, how can i automatically reload only the datatables if possible. here is my ajax jquery code

```
function delete_province(PROV_ID)
{
  if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
  {
    // ajax delete data to database
      $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('Provinces/ajax_delete')?>/"+PROV_ID,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(PROV_ID)
        {
           //if success reload ajax table
             $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
             reload_table();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error deleting data');
        }
    });

  }
}
```

table

```
  </head> 
  <body>

  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <a href = '<?php echo base_url().'Provinces/add_view'; ?>' class = 'btn btn-success pull-left fa fa-plus'>&nbsp Add New</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Province</th>
          <th style="width:125px;">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Province</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is function reload_table()?

Comment: ah okay. so it is a function. haha. i deleted some from this codes that i think was not necessary. haha!